# Record a video presentation from my computer

Tags: video-capture, presentation

I'd like to make a presentation on my computer that records sounds and shows all the necessary mouse-clicks, and any typing I do in a window or a form and record the results into some sort of file for playback later.

It doesn't matter if the file is MPG or AVI as long as the file can be played back in Windows Media Player.

What sort of application would anyone suggest to do this?  I've seen a number of web casts that do this, but it never dawned on me what sort of software that would be useful in doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest for CamStudio as it is free and open source software.

**NOTE** Camstudio [reportedly contains malware](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=camstudio+malware)

Comment: This seems to do the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You should try [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.asp).  It's easy to use (I used it before) and  it can export to AVI, Flash and Windows media

Answer (score 2):

[CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) - it's free and open source

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Microsoft Office Live](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/livemeeting/HA102026531033.aspx).

Its very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend PresentationTube, a new way for recording and sharing video presentations. Free and easy to learn. http://presentationtube.com/

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't meet your exact usecase. At all. BUT!

Give Presentious a try. For example: http://presentio.us/view/p1tcHs

There's nothing to install and it's super simple.